# Shifting data from Memory address

Tags: c

How to shift the bytes from an address. If i am storing the characters "ABCDEF" in 16-bit address
 starting from 0x210A.

```
0x210A - 'A'
  0x210B - 'B'
  0x210C - 'C'
  0x210E - 'E'
  0x210F - 'F'
```

These i want to shift 10 times. Nothing but, this need to store in from 0x2100

```
 0x2100 - 'A'
  0x2101 - 'B'
  0x2102 - 'C'
  0x2103 - 'E'
  0x2104 - 'F'
```

I know shifting can be done with taking one variable. i want to shift byte from one address to other.

Comment: use `memcpy` or `memmove`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [memmove](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove), e.g. like this:

```
#include <string.h>

const char * src = (char *)0x210a;  // source address
char * dst = (char *)0x2100;        // destination address
const size_t len = 5;               // no of bytes 

memmove(dst, src, len);
```